# Individual UITabBaritem tint color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to implement a [custom UITabbar](http://imgur.com/lCtYL8R).

Anything I found involves overlaying a Rectangle over the tabbarItem.
So is there any straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change an individual tabBar items tint color use the following

```
let tabBar = (self.tabBarController?.tabBar)! as UITabBar
tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 120/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1)
```

Add this code in your `viewWillAppear`.

**Update**

```
let tabBar = (self.tabBarController?.tabBar)! as UITabBar
// Change this index to your selected tabBar index
// 1 = second item
let index = CGFloat(1)
let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(itemWidth * index, 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: Int(index))
```

Add this code in your `viewWillAppear`. If you want to load this from the app start I would recommend to add it in your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but that only changes the icon color, I want to change the background color of every single tabbaritem.

Comment: After some tweaking I finally got it, check the update @AndresVlaeminck